# jQuery, unable to store data returned by $.get function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to turn **div#sidebar** into a sidebar in my app. My code looks like the one below.

```
$('#sidebar').userProfile();

jQuery.fn.userProfile = function() {
  $.get('/users/profile', function(data){ $(this).html(data); });
};
```

It didnt work because, I found the ***this* (inside the $.get function)** here contexts to the get request and not $('#sidebar'). Then I tried something like below.

```
$('#sidebar').userProfile();

#This doesnot work
jQuery.fn.userProfile = function() {
  var side_bar = null;
  $.get('/users/profile', function(data){ side_bar = data; });
  $(this).html(side_bar);
  console.log(side_bar);
};
```

This doesnt work either. In firebug console I see Null which I am setting on top when I am declaring the variable.Atlast I made it work by changing my code to something like below by hardcoding the selector.

```
#This works, but I cannot turn any element to a sidebar which is sick.
jQuery.fn.userProfile = function() {
  $.get('/users/profile', function(data){ $('#sidebar').html(data); });
};
```

But this is not I wanted because I wanted to turn any element to a sidebar. Where am I goin wrong or which is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#sidebar').userProfile();

jQuery.fn.userProfile = function() {
  var elem = this;
  $.get('/users/profile', function(data){
    $(elem).html(data);
  });
};
```

Since `this` changes with each context, it's an often used technique to store `this` in another variable at your earliest convenience to capture the right context.

Your second example doesn't work because the `.get` callback is executed asynchronously at an undefined later time (when the data comes back).